# jQuery Autocomplete - Key Down to results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am creating a simple autocomplete form with a single textbox field. On every keyup, I cycle through a DB table and populate a DIV (#listKeywords) - located just below the textbox.

Here's what the results look like...

```
<div id="listKeywords">
    <div class="acListItem">Product 1</div>
    <div class="acListItem">Product 2</div>
    <div class="acListItem">Product 3</div>
</div>
```

If I click on any of the results, that result populates the textbox (as desired).
If I press the down arrow on my keyboard, nothing happens.

Q: How can I incorporate keyboard functionality to where I press the down arrow and focus is put on the first item/product in the listKeywords DIV?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not want to use one of the many already existing autocomplete plugins such as: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you simply handle the keyup event of the text box and alter your div items with a special class to make it look as though they are selected.